# Elements left in Java stack when Fisher-Yates shuffling?

Tags: java, stack, shuffle

I'm having a little trouble with some code I'm writing. Basically, I'm trying to "shuffle" a stack collection like a deck of cards, but for some reason, one of the temporary stacks I'm using won't empty completely, and this causes an empty collection exception on the next run around. I traced the code and the output by hand, and the elements are being left in temporary stack 1 (the code is below). I'm really not sure why this is happening! If you have any insight on this, it'd be really helpful.

Here is a link to the problem method: http://pastebin.com/cxJCmemZ

```
public void shuffleCards(LinkedStack<UnoCard> deck) {
        int tempIndex;
        LinkedStack<UnoCard> tempCardStack1 = new LinkedStack<UnoCard>();
        LinkedStack<UnoCard> tempCardStack2 = new LinkedStack<UnoCard>();

        //Fisher-Yates shuffle
        for (int i = (deck.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
            tempIndex = ((int)(i * Math.random()));

            System.out.println("i is: " + i);
            System.out.println("tempIndex is: " + tempIndex);

            //swap if cards are different
            if (tempIndex != i) {
                //pop face down cards up to first card onto temporary stack
                System.out.println("Popping up to first card");
                for(int j = 0; j <= tempIndex; j++) {
                    UnoCard tempCard = faceDownCards.pop();
                    System.out.println(tempCard.toString());
                    tempCardStack1.push(tempCard);
                }

                //pop face down cards up to second card onto temporary stack
                System.out.println("Popping up to second card");
                for(int j = (tempIndex + 1); j <= i; j++) {
                    UnoCard tempCard = faceDownCards.pop();
                    System.out.println(tempCard.toString());
                    tempCardStack2.push(tempCard);
                }

                //replace first card in second card position
                System.out.println("Replacing first card");
                UnoCard tempCard = tempCardStack1.pop();
                System.out.println(tempCard.toString());
                faceDownCards.push(tempCard);

                //place second card in temporary stack
                System.out.println("Transferring second card");
                tempCard = tempCardStack2.pop();
                System.out.println(tempCard.toString());
                tempCardStack1.push(tempCard);

                //replace temporary stack
                System.out.println("Replacing second stack");
                for(int j = 0; j < tempCardStack2.size(); j++) {
                    tempCard = tempCardStack2.pop();
                    System.out.println(tempCard.toString());
                    faceDownCards.push(tempCard);
                }

                //replace second card in first card position
                System.out.println("Replacing second card");
                tempCard = tempCardStack1.pop();
                System.out.println(tempCard.toString());
                faceDownCards.push(tempCard);

                //replace temporary stack
                System.out.println("Replacing first stack");
                for(int j = 0; j < tempCardStack1.size(); j++) {
                    tempCard = tempCardStack1.pop();
                    System.out.println(tempCard.toString());
                    faceDownCards.push(tempCard);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Next time you should just add the code. It wasn't that much. Generally people don't want to follow links to code (especially since that link could disappear in the future and thus make the question and answer less valuable).

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. Thank you for correcting this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you pop a stack the size shrinks so the for loop will only run for size/2 times

so the ending loops should really be

```
while(!tempCardStack1.isEmpty()){
    tempCard = tempCardStack1.pop();
    System.out.println(tempCard.toString());
    faceDownCards.push(tempCard);
}
```